# Limit Memory Usage When Zipping Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I currently use ionic to zip a number of photos and then send them to the user on a browser. Essentially something like this.

```
using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile())
{
      byte[] data = client.DownloadData("photo.png");

      zipFile.AddEntry("photo.png", data);

      Response.ClearContent();
      Response.ClearHeaders();
      Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Media.zip");

      zipFile.Save(Response.OutputStream);
}
```

However sometimes there are many photo's going up to 15 mb's and there are many of them.

As such memory gets completely used and it runs out before it can finish creating the zip file. Is there a way I can accomplish zipping files and sending them to a user without using such vast amounts of memory? Maybe a different approach entirely?

Comment: are you aiming for compression with the zip file or just for a single container for the group of photos? The zip compression won't gain you much trying to compress the already compressed png / jpg files. As Jon suggests, streaming is the way to go.

Comment: It is to have a single container more so than compression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me like you'd be better off writing the file to disk (or a database) somewhere, ideally in a streaming fashion... then give the client a link which allows the file to be downloaded - again, in a streaming fashion. Basically, try to avoid ever requiring the complete file to be in memory at any time.

Comment: @Adam Take a look at SharpZipLib - it contains `Stream` implementations that support compression/decompression in this manner. http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

Comment: Thanks Jon. Those were my thoughts generally as well. Just a question though, every time I add an entry to a zip file on disk, will it require loading that entire zip file back up in memory?

Comment: @Adam: It shouldn't require loading it all into memory, no - but I'm not 100% sure that most APIs allow you to easily add to an existing file at all.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jon's suggestion on moving everything from memory and switching to streaming.

Since you are talking about already compressed images even more extreme approach can be taken: you can create Zip with non-compressed files on the fly directly from files and immediately stream results to browser without intermediate creation of Zip in memory/on disk. I don't know if existing libraries will allow you to do so or you'll need to write your own based on the specification (see [Wikipedia on Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) for links).

Side note: it is unclear from your sample if you need to store data between requests, but if you do consider some out-of-process storage for files and not session state. If you handle large amount of data - make sure to use x64 process for IIS if possible.